# How can I set the spacing below a cmidrule equal to that above?

Tags: tables, booktabs, vertical-spacing

I'd like the spacing below the rules in my tables to equal the spacing above. By default, the below-spacing is smaller.

First: How can I find the spacing I need to add, without trial-and-error adding of tiny heights?

Second: My document has many tables with several midrules. Is there a way to add the spacing below all of them without changing the code for every instance?

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{thirty-} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
foo & one & two & three \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing above and below the  `\cmidrule` lines *is* the same. What your example overlooks is that the placement of the *baseline*  of text in the row above the rules has to take into account that some letters -- notably, `g`, `j`, `p`, `q`, and `y` in the Latin alphabet -- have parts that protrude below the baseline. Please replace `foo & one & two & three` with `ggg & ppp & qqq & yyy`, recompile your example, and observe much more even amounts of whitespace above and below the cmidrules. If anything, there's now *less* whitespace above than below the rules.

Comment: Adding to Mico's comment, if you replace the `1&2&3&4` below your `\cmidrule`s with something that doesn't have ascenders, like `a&c&e&x`, the space below the `\cmidrule`s will be larger (even though the spacing of the baselines will not have changed).

Comment: @Mico and @schtandard -- thank you, I replaced all cells with `xxx`, and it is clear that the spacings are equal. In my actual document, the texts in cells have ascenders, like in my example. How can I make the spacing take this into account? In the example in the post, I think there is a visual imbalance.

Comment: Here is an example more similar to an actual table, where the parentheses exaggerate the spacing imbalance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8LQI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that the subheaders have no depth (no letter has descenders), but LaTeX always ensures that a row is at least as high and deep as a strut, so the height and depth are a bit more than the height and depth of all letters *in the alphabet*.

No “fix” would be needed if one letter has a descender:

[image]

If you don't like the effect in the *specific and particular* case when no letter in the header row has descenders, you can fix it by adding suitable negative space.

Here I use the depth of a letter with a descender, namely “g”.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{thirty-} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
foo & one & two & three \\
\addlinespace[-\fontchardp\font`g]
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Taking non-existing ascenders/descenders into account was confusing after spending time in TikZ, where I often had to compensate myself for those spacings when relevant. (By the way, in your fog example, I still find the table imbalanced. My eye is bothered by the differences in spacing below one/two/thre and above 2/3/4. Maybe I'd be even more bothered by a tiny space below `g` though!)

Comment: @Anna TBH, I'd never remove space in the “fog” example, but personal judgment is involved and the “real” table should be looked at. In any case, reserve these adjustments to the very final revision of the document.

Comment: @Anna - You wrote, "My eye is bothered by the differences in spacing below one/two/thre and above 2/3/4." Do familiarize yourself with the distinction between *mathematical* and *visual* (or *aesthetic*) balance. Imposing equal distances above and below cmidrules in no way assures that the table will *look* balanced. To the contrary, to achieve decent visual balance it's common to provide more whitespace *above* an object (here: the 2 3 4  row) than *below* an object (here: two three four). To my eye, egreg's second screenshot possesses visual balance.

Comment: @Mico I certainly agree about the second screenshot, so I think we're of the same mind and eye!